# Atualizar informações recebidas do arduino

Tags: android, socket, arduino, bluetooth

Tenho feito um aplicativo que interage com uma cabeça robótica com Arduíno e gostaria de saber como faço para receber automaticamente todos os dados do robô sem ter que acionar o envio de algum comando

Funcionaria semelhante a um log, sempre mantendo atualizado o app das informações recebidas do robô

Essa é a thread que tenho para configurar o recebimento das informações

```
 class ThreadServidor extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                if(socket != null){
                    /*serverSocket.close();*/
                    // Depois que alguém conectou, pega a InputStream para ler as mensagens
                    in = socket.getInputStream();
                    // Fica em loop, para receber as mensagens
                    while(true) {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        updateViewMensagem(line);
                    }
                }
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

E esse é o método que mostra na tela as informações recebidas

```
private void updateViewMensagem(String s) {
        if((!s.isEmpty()) && s != null){
            if(qtdLinhas == 10){
                list = "";
                qtdLinhas = 1;
            }
            if(ordem == 7){
                list += s;
                ordem = 1;
                qtdLinhas++;
            }else{
                list += s + " - ";
                ordem++;
            }
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    if(list != null){
                        logInfo.setText(list);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Obs:Não sei como coloar o código entre as marcações necessárias aqui no fórum(ainda.....)

Obrigado.

Comment: Aqui não é fórum...

Comment: Obrigado @acklay